# Are there any good philosophical arguments for or against Cantor's theorem, other than the ones that Cantor came up with?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, infinity

I am looking for philosophical arguments for and against Cantor's theorem other than the ones Cantor came up with, if you know any, can you present them or a link to them?

I post this in philosophy since in the mathematical realm it is a settled issue as mathematics only cares if it is proved, yet philosophy asks why is it true, not just is it or is it not true. If we understood why the argument works, we might be able to answer questions like "why is there no cardinality between the rationals and the reals?"

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that "nobody understands Cantor's theorem"?

Comment: It follows from "even now we accept it because it is proved, not for any other reason" else he would have said "even now we accept it because it is proved and we understand it, not for any other reason". I have never found anyone who understands it, they only understand the proof, not the actual theory.

Comment: Cantor's th is a mathematical theorem: we can easily understand it.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA , Okay you disagree with Wilfrid Hodges who said

“But then we come to Cantor’s result, and all intuition fails us. Until Cantor first proved his theorem, nothing like its conclusion was in anybody’s mind’s eye. And even now we accept it because it is proved, not for any other reason.”
http://www.logic.univie.ac.at/~ykhomski/ST2013/Hodges.pdf
last paragraph page 3

Comment: The proof of the th is very simple; in the finite case, we can list all the subsets of a set **A** and check that they are "more then" the elements of **A**. Cantor's argument is general: of course, we can deny the existence of an "actually" (in the Aristotelian sense) *infinite* set and all the seemingly paradoxical aspects disappear.

Comment: Cantor's proof has been used by Russell to derive its own paradox, which has nothing to do with infinity. The issue is with *infinity*, not with the proof.

Comment: Welcome to this SE! Although the question may be closed I hope you continue to ask and answer questions here.

Comment: "It has been said that nobody understands Cantor's theorem" Who says that? It's extraordinarily simple, a three-liner accessible to a high school student.

Comment: @IvanHieno I read your linked PDF.  I now understand what's tripping you up.  Here's a way to break down "for no other reason". The author is effectively positing that there are two reasons people choose to believe something: either it is "obvious"/"common sense"/"intuitive", or it's been proven. Here, when he says "because it's been proven, and for no other reason", the implication is "Cantor's theorem is true, we know this because it was proven true, not because it's immediately obvious or intuitive". Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a very good case of a question that pushes your own personal philosophy. You can restructure this question in a much more neutral way if your goal is to look for philosophical literature on this topic. However, it seems very readily apparent that this is not your goal.

Comment: @Not_Here , I admit to having a bias, I can't help but to see this problem differently. I have found that most people get very militant toward anyone who dissents on this question, thus I would truly welcome an argument that would allow me to rejoin the fold.

Comment: It is often said (after Feynman) that nobody understands quantum mechanics also, yet we are justified at holding it true. Understanding, desirable though it is, is not a precondition of justification. This said, the author of the linked article is factually mistaken in that "until Cantor first proved his theorem... nothing like its conclusion was in anybody's mind's eye". The idea that the continuum is vastly bigger than integers, *if* it is to be made from points, was (and is) "intuitive", and was expressed before Cantor's proof. That rationals are equal to integers was more surprising.

Comment: You write "I have found that most people get very militant toward anyone who dissents on this question" - this might be connected to your claim "I have never found anyone who understands it, they only understand the proof, not the actual theory." One of the reasons that I personally get frustrated discussing such issues is the frequency with which the other person assumes that *I must not* understand the situation at a "sufficiently deep level" simply because I haven't been able to explain the situation to their satisfaction. (cont'd)

Comment: You are personally not satisfied, so far, with the explanations given. Fair enough, and I'm (at least in principle, my time is limited in reality) happy to continue trying to explain it. But the leap from that to the claim that **nobody** understands it is ... really arrogant, to be honest. Even leaning on Hodges (or anyone else) doesn't really help here, because you still find a reason to take their claim (as you interpret it - I actually think you're off-base there) over the contrary claims of others.

Answer (score 2):

Cantor's theorem is a prime instance of a diagonalization argument, but far from being the only one. There is nothing particularly mysterious or un-intuitive about diagonalization. I do not know what motivates Hodges to claim otherwise, but he his quite certainly expressing a minority viewpoint here.

Diagonalization does not require any specific mathematical foundations to work, but tends to go through for all of them. There is in particular no real justification for any attempt to resolve conflicts with any pre-existing philosophical baggage regarding infinity by faulting diagonalization.

Comment: Cantor's theorem is not a diagonalization. You might be thinking of Cantor's diagonal argument. OP's link gave the Wiki page for Cantor's theorem, which says there's no surjection from a set to its powerset.

Comment: @user4894 Cantor's theorem is diagonalization, as a special case of Lawvere's fixed point theorem.

Comment: Ok at that level I agree. But then your answer's suitability as a response to the OP comes into question. What you said is true yet at a very different level than the question hence not a helpful response. Is my point too picky or do you agree?